# Nginx server not working with Symlink and giving: File not found (Laravel Project)

Tags: laravel, nginx, symlink

Its a Laravel Project
My content directory is: `/home/ubuntu/domain.name/laravel_server/code`
My www-web directory is: `/var/www/domain.name/html`

symlink is created from content to www-web

`sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/domain.name/laravel_server/code /var/www/domain.name/html`

And now this directory `/var/www/domain.name/html` display content of `/home/ubuntu/domain.name/laravel_server/code`

But nginx is not reading content and giving me **File not found**.

```
server {

    index index.php;
    
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;
    
    root /var/www/domain.name/html/public/;
    
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size on;
        disable_symlinks off;
        index  index.nginx-debian.html index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        root /var/www/domain.name/html/public/;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 2M;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 2M;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.domain.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    listen 80;
    
    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/domain.name/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/domain.name

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/domain.name
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
sudo find /var/www/domain.name -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/domain.name -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;   
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUSfU.png)

**My website should work with symlink content.**

Comment: Try moving the `disable_symlinks off;` line one level up under `server {`  directly

Answer (score 0):

you've disabled symbolic links using `disable_symlinks off;`
you should also not be using the root directive inside a location block unless absolutely necessary.

update your Nginx configuration to look something like this:

```
server {

    root /var/www/domain.name/html/public/;
    index index.php;

    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.domain.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain.name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name domain.name www.domain.name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

remember to restart or reload your Nginx after making changes to the configuration file.
also, ensure your symbolic link permissions are correct.

Comment: `disable_symlinks off` is a double negative so actually enables symlinks